# Subsetting in R columns of data frames stored in list based on their indexes stored in another list

Tags: r

I am new to handling data frames stored in list, I apologise, but I have the following question:

Suppose I have multiple data frames stored in list, I would like to subset a certain number of columns which is always different from each data frame based on the indexes for the first column  till the index of the last column.

Example:

```
    df1

    c1. c2. c3 c4 c5 
    1.  a.  4.  d. 7
    2.  b.  5.  e. 8
    3.  c.  6.  f. 9

    df2

    c1. c2. c2_1 c3 c3_1  c4 c5 
    1.  a.  a1    4  4a    d. 7
    2.  b.  b1    5  5a    e. 8
    3.  c.  c1    6  6a    f. 9

df3

    c1. c2. c4 c5 
    1.  a.  d. 7
    2.  b.  e. 8
    3.  c.  f. 9

Output df1

df1

    c1. c2. c3 c4 
    1.  a.  4.  d.
    2.  b.  5.  e.
    3.  c.  6.  f.

Output df2

df2

    c1. c2. c2_1 c3 c3_1  c4  
    1.  a.  a1    4  4a    d. 
    2.  b.  b1    5  5a    e. 
    3.  c.  c1    6  6a    f. 

Ouput df3

df1

    c1. c2. c4 c5 
    1.  a.  d. 7
    2.  b.  e. 8
    3.  c.  f. 9
```

Let's suppose I want to subset from column c1 till column c4, however, column c4 has different index in all the data frames stored in the list.

So, I have got the index for all the c1 columns and c4 columns in all the data frames with this loop.
The data frames are store in list_df

```
c1_index<-list()
for(i in seq_along(list_df)){
  c1_index[[i]] <-which(colnames(list_df[[i]])== "c1")
}

c4_index<-list()
for(i in seq_along(list_df)){
  c4_index[[i]] <-which(colnames(list_df[[i]])== "c4")
}
```

Then I merge the two list of start and end index:

```
c1_c4_index <- mapply(append, c1_index, c4_index, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

I have now a list of integers with the indexes of the columns I would like to subset.

```
str(c1_c4_index)
List of 3
$ : int 1 4
$ : int 1 6
$ : int 1 3
```

Now, how to write a for loop which is subsetting the columns in all the df in list_df based on their indexes stored in c1_c4_index?

I wrote something like this but it does not seem to be working:

```
list_new<-list()
for(i in seq_along(c1_c4_index)){
  list_new[[i]]<-list_df[[i]][, list_df[[i]] %in% c1_c4_index[[i]]]
}
```

Any help highly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution:

```
list_new<-list()
for(i in seq_along(list_df)){
  list_new[[i]]<-list_df[[i]][c(c1_index[[i]]:c4_index[[i]])]
}
```

Please, if anybody knows how to do this in a more efficient way, let me know